# How to generate new random value for each scenario in protractor node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

Am able to generate a random string in protractor node js BDD framework.But the problem is, the same value is being hold for all the scenarios when batch execution is triggered and the tests are getting failing because of the same value used in all the scenarios.Can someone please suggest how to generate new random value everytime a scenario is invoked during batch execution and the same value should be passed for all the methods for that scenario.

Note : I have declared it as global variable to be used across the methods for a particular scenario.

Comment: when you say scenrio what do you refer to? to a spec file? describe block? or test suite? I'd also be benefitial to add what you currently have

Comment: yes a describe block, I believe. As it is BDD framework, we have scenarios in feature file. So comparing feature file to spec file and scenario to describe block. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

this

```
// 1.spec.js
let generateString = (length) => {
        let letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
            str = '';

        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            str += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
        }

        return str;
}

let randomString = generateString(7);
describe(`Scenario`, () => {
    it('1', async () => {
        console.log(randomString);
    });

    it('2', async () => {
        console.log(randomString);
    });

    it('3', async () => {
        console.log(randomString);
    });
});
```

will produce this

```
Jasmine started
saxijqt

  Scenario
    ✓ 1 (0.014 sec)
saxijqt
    ✓ 2 (0.035 sec)
saxijqt
    ✓ 3 (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution I will try to implement this with BDD framework

Comment: bdd is cucumber? I never worked with it, but I'm pretty sure the approach should be the same, just declare a variable on the top of the file and it will be available across all functions in that file